# How can I extend a Doctrine column definition of a mapped superclass without overriding the whole definition?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Given the following [Mapped Superclass](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) which is fixed and cannot be changed:

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass() */
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false) */
    protected $age;

    // ...
}
```

And given my concrete entity:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class ConcreteEntity extends AbstractEntity { // ... }
```

How can my `ConcreteEntity` *extend* the `age` definition of it's mapped superclass and make it nullable?

I know about the [Attribute Override](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override) feature, but it would require me to override the whole definition (i.e. specify `type = "integer"` again). I just want to *extend* it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe an *EventSubscriber* to the [Load ClassMetadata Event](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event) to achieve this goal. It is called after Doctrine read your entity's metadata and can be used to alter it.

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class YourSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {
    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [Events::loadClassMetadata];
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs) {
        /** @var ClassMetadata $metadata */
        $metadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        if ($metadata->getName() != 'F\Q\N\ConcreteEntity') {
            return;
        }

        // Get field mapping of the age field.
        $fieldMapping = $metaData->fieldMappings['age'];
        $fieldMapping['nullable'] = true;
        $metadata->setAttributeOverride($fieldName, $fieldMapping);
    }
}
```

Make sure to attach this listener to Doctrine's EventManager, as described [in the Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html). If you're using Symfony 2/3, follow the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) instead.

Comment: Nice that you're answering your own question/findings over here, thereby helping others. More people should do that.